# Added Json.NET as a reference, accepted then flagged as not built or available

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reference, json.net, orchardcms

so I need to add the Newtonsoft.Json.dll to the references of my Orchard project.(from http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6MRzbJBvM7c)

So I use Nuget http://www.nuget.org/packages/NewtonSoft.Json/ which installs it to the Orchard.Web project. I then add the reference to my own project and select browse/Orchard.Web/bin and select Newtonsoft.Json

I then build the project and everything seems to work fine, later on when I build I get errors about Newtsonsoft.Json does not exist, i check the list of references in my own project and there is a yellow and black explanation mark beside it which says it is not available or does not exist.....

I thought it was something I done, so went back through the process and it worked fine, then later on the same thing happened....does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Does the library you reference actually exist where it should be? Are you referenceing specfic version? If so, check that the version of the lib match the version reference expects.

Answer (score 1):

Orchard does not place all of its assemblies in the bin because of the dynamic compile nature of Modules. These assemblies are created at runtime and placed into App_Data\Dependencies. Because of this single location, everything must be on the same version of the assembly or you may end up with Binding conflicts. Which gets us to the next part...

Orchard does not use NuGet. Instead, all of its references come from the lib folder to help ensure that everything is on the same assembly version of a dependent assembly. Newtonsoft.Json already exists within Orchard, and can be found within lib. Reference the assembly from /lib/newtonsoft.json/newtonsoft.json.dll in your Module, and everything should be working again.